# how to copy existing file from AWS s3 bucket which is private

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, phpmyadmin

I have used copy function for copying the file.My code work without using s3 bucket both in local and IIS But when i used S3 bucket i got this error.

> Error executing "PutObject" on
> "{bucket_path}/local-iportalDocuments/96/building.jpeg"; AWS HTTP
> error: Client error: `PUT {{bucket_path}}/local-iportalDocuments/96/building.jpeg` resulted in a
> `403 Forbidden` response:\n\n`AccessDenied`Access
> Denied3BGXVF (truncated...)\n AccessDenied
> (client): Access Denied - \n`AccessDenied`Access
> Denied3BGXVF8J5RST47DW9tUMIzQGZyiKdb4+Vwj10EWFxUiMYzmdaCCNVVfzuSRzAhj4YvVssE0+OA12IeW3WTu2K+POr0s=",
> "exception": "Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception

I use this line of code for copy :

```
$mediaItem = $oldModel->getMedia('document_files')->find($file['id']);
$copiedMediaItem = $mediaItem->copy($model, 'document_files', config('app.media_disk'));
```

..Need Help

Comment: Have you properly set up authentication for the S3 bucket?

Comment: Yes I have.If I make bucket public it work but the bucket is private.